# Multidatespiscker: highlight a range of dates

Tags: jquery, calendar, highlight

I have to highlight a user defined range of dates in a calendar. I decided to use [multidatespicker](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/)

User select 2 dates, and all days between that days may to be highlighted. I'm not good with `JavaScript`/`jQuery`, can anyone help me please. I have lost a lot of time with this, and still haven't got any idea.

I read about [timeframe](http://stephencelis.github.com/timeframe/#example_information); but I'm using prime faces, and it is incompatible with `prototy.js` used in *timeframe*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin you chose to use doesn't have any methods that support that usage out of the box, you'd have to code this functionality yourself.

Take a look over here it seems like this person was looking for something similar to what you need:
[jQuery UI Datepicker - Date range - Highlight days in between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831512/jquery-ui-datepicker-date-range-highlight-days-in-between)

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll follow that post

Comment: Finally i used that, and worsk very well!!
http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html#range